# Error C6011:Dereferencing NULL pointer 'mat'. C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my project when it's have a notify when I change from c to c++ code.

```
int **mat

void randFill()
{
    int i, j;
    mat = (int**)calloc(6, sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = (int*)calloc(6, sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
            mat[i][j] = getRand();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the C++ version of your code?

Comment: @NathanPierson It's Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6011?view=msvc-160

Comment: Okay, a bit more pointedly: If this is an attempt at C++ code, what's with all the `calloc`? Even if you don't want to use `std::array` you can do something like `int[6][6] mat;` instead of this.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I already read that but It's can not change

Comment: If you can't change your code, what help do you expect anyone to be able to provide?

Comment: @NathanPierson yeah I know but right now I study about pointer and this one make me confuse a lot

Comment: @NathanPierson Here is all my code make error in c++ https://codeshare.io/amldRW, And this one can run normally in c: https://codeshare.io/aygjyo. I want to change to c++. I did everything except this can not work for me

Comment: I don't believe that's actually a compiler error/warning anyway, at least I don't see it at warning level 4 with warnings as errors on. It's an Intellisense warning. If you're studying about pointers then checking if they are NULL before you use them should be part of that study.

Comment: @RetiredNinja for me it keep warning like this https://photos.app.goo.gl/7z3KxF64xqsdxQHJ8

Comment: Yes, because you have "Build + IntelliSense" selected. Still not sure what you want us to tell you. If you want that IntelliSense warning to go away you need to check the pointers for NULL before you use them. If you won't change the code then get used to seeing them.